# What are the steps/tricks/tips to construct a Büchi automaton from a given language?

Tags: automata, buchi-automata

Let's say I have this language: $(a + bc)^∗((b + c)a^ω + (abb^∗)^ω)$

It seems pretty complicated, where should I begin with if I were to construct a Büchi automaton?

I've been doing it the following way with smaller language sets:

- a $^*$ operator is usually a path coming from a node to the same node.
- a $+$ draws 2 branches

how would $^ω$ be represented? there are other operators, which I have not seen yet, what are they and how would they also be represented?

Pardon me if this is a silly question, but I'd rather ask than not knowing the answer ever.

Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Thang

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct an NBA for an $\omega$-regular expression $r$ by induction on the generating sequence of $r$, using the constructive [closure properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BCchi_automaton#Closure_properties) of NBAs.

You can see some examples [here](https://www7.in.tum.de/um/courses/auto/ws1516/slides1213/omega-automata-powerpoint.pdf)

Comment: can you be more specific? or give me an example, please?

Comment: The construction usually leads to huge automata, so I can't really draw them here. Try looking at examples of the conversion from regular expressions to NFAs, you'll get the idea.

Comment: @csessh Look in your course materials; the construction should be in there. IIRC, it's very similar to Thompson's construction for finite automata.

Comment: this topic was briefly gone over in my course material/lecture, that's why I couldn't get much out of it and have to look to Google. but thanks for the keywords suggestion, it's getting a bit clearer to me now.